# Why is CPT symmetry necessary to prove the spin-statistics theorem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, quantum-spin, spin-statistics, cpt-symmetry

I was reading the Wikipedia article on the spin-statistics theorem. It has [a section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem#Suggestive_bogus_argument) going through a "suggestive bogus argument", where they [rotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)) products of fields. To show why it doesn't work, they use the counterexample of an anticommuting, spin $0$, non-relativistic field. The reason why it doesn't work is because the product has zero expected value in any state. Will the argument work if you assume that $\langle0|R(\pi)\phi(x)\phi(-x)|0\rangle$ is not zero when $x$ is spacelike? [The proof they use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem#Proof) assumes this anyway because it follows from assumption 4. What I am trying to figure out is why a [Euclidean time rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry#Derivation_of_the_CPT_theorem) is needed and just a space rotation won't work.

Comment: J.G. kindly added links to my question, but he linked "rotate" to "parity" and "time rotation" to "time reversal symmetry". Then Qmechanic edited the text to match the links. Was this done because I misused the terms or was it a mistake?

Comment: I did my best to capture what I think you were referring to, while @Qmechanic edited your text to match my guesses' usual terminology. _Nobody_ says "time rotation". Multiplying a $1$- or $3$-dimensional quantity by $-1$ might be more popularly termed a _reflection_ (it actually is still a rotation, albeit an improper one in both cases due to the dimension being odd, making the determinant $(-1)^{1,\,3}=-1$). But for clarity, people talk of time reversal & parity transformation, often mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry).

Comment: "time rotation" was the term the article used, I didnt know that was non-standard terminalogy. Thanks for correcting it

Comment: I've reviewed Wikipedia's usage. It turns out time reversal is one _ingredient_ of their "time rotation": "The rotation plane includes time, and a rotation in a plane involving time in the Euclidean theory defines a CPT transformation in the Minkowski theory". Any answer to your question will explain why the P part alone isn't enough to make the argument work in a Lorentz-invariant theory.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect that